# How Do I Set The Bitclock in a Make File for AVR?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, avrdude

I'm following Chapter 2 of Elliot Williams' book Make: AVR Programming. I'm on an iMac.

I get a success message in Terminal when I input:

avrdude -p m328 -c usbasp -v -B 10

So, I know that my programmer and micro controller are working.

(If I don't set the Bitclock to 10 then it throws an error.)

My problem is working with the Make file. When I try "make flash" I get an error message.

> avr-gcc -Os -g -std=gnu99 -Wall -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields
>   -fpack-struct -fshort-enums  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -DF_CPU=1000000UL   -DBAUD=9600UL -I. -I../../AVR-Programming-Library -mmcu=atmega328 -c -o blinkLED.o blinkLED.c avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,blinkLED.map  -Wl,--gc-sections  -mmcu=atmega328 blinkLED.o ../../AVR-Programming-Library/USART.o  -o blinkLED.elf avr-objcopy -j
>   .text -j .data -O ihex blinkLED.elf blinkLED.hex avrdude -c usbasp -p
>   atmega328  -U flash:w:blinkLED.hex
>
> avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1  avrdude:
>   initialization failed, rc=-1
>            Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
>            this check.
>
> avrdude done.  Thank you.
>
> make: *** [flash] Error 1

I think that the problem is that the Bitclock isn't set in the Make file, and I'm not sure how to do so. (If I have some other error, please let me know. I'm guessing.) The Make file can be found on gitHub at:
[blinkLED Make File](https://github.com/hexagon5un/AVR-Programming/blob/master/Chapter02_Programming-AVRs/blinkLED/Makefile)

I have set the MCU = atmega328 (which is the micro controller that I'm using.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `PROGRAMMER_ARGS` assignment in the `flash_usbasp` rule to include the proper avrdude arguments.

```
flash_usbasp: PROGRAMMER_ARGS = ...
```

Comment: Vasquez-Abrams. Awesome that worked. I invoked it with "make flash_usbasp"